How can I retrieve Bazel labels for a list of files?
Suppose I have a list of files:

some/path/to/file1.cpp
some/path/to/file2.cpp

My goal is to determine if Bazel recognizes these files and obtain their corresponding labels.
Initially, I attempted to utilize queries as follows:
bazel query "set(some/path/to/file1.cpp some/path/to/file2.cpp)"

This approach partially works. However, if any specified file is not within Bazel's dependencies, it returns an error stating "no such target ...". While I could potentially add the --keep_going flag and hope that only "no such target" errors occur (and no other meaningful errors), this feels like a suboptimal solution.
As a second approach, I attempted to manually generate labels by locating the nearest BUILD file and constructing labels from there. However, this method fails when a local repository is involved.
Is there any better way of doing this?
